# Ealasticsearch results exactly as parameter

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I'm trying to filter logs based on the domain name. For example I only want the results of domain: bh250.example.com.

When I use the following query:

http://localhost:9200/_search?pretty&size=150&q=domainname=bh250.example.com

the first 3 results have a domain name: bh250.example.com where the 4th having bh500.example.com

I have read several documentations on how to query to Elasticsearch but I seem to miss something. I only want results having 100% match with the parameter.

UPDATE!! After question from Val

```
queryFilter = Q("match", domainname="bh250.example.com")

search=Search(using=dev_client, index="logstash-2016.09.21").query("bool", filter=queryFilter)[0:20]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, you just need to make a small change:

```
http://localhost:9200/_search?pretty&size=150&q=domainname:"bh250.example.com"
                                                          ^                  ^
                                                          |                  |
                                   use colon instead of equal... and double quotes
```

Comment: Is there a way to add the colon and the double quotes inside python elasticsearch dsl

Comment: How are you doing it now?